Approximation of ln(cosh(x))?
Does anyone know an approximation for $\ln(\cosh(x))$?
I am aware of the approximation $\ln(\cosh(x))\approx x$, but is only valid for very large values of $x$ (I tried using for small values, but the inaccuracy was to large for my purposes)
Is there an approximation for values of $x$ in a range close to $0<x<2$ (ideally one that doesn't make algebra extremely difficult)? If there is no approximation can I just create a function which follows $\ln(\cosh(x))$ closely in that range and use that as an approximation?
For context I am trying to solve for $c$ in $h=\frac{m}{c}\ln\left(\cosh\left(\frac{tg\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{mg}}\right)\right)$, an expansion of an equation found here: link
In the worst-case scenario, does anyone know a software to solve this numerically? Ideally, I could just input values for $m$, $c$, $t$, and $g$, and it would solve for c.

Taylor approximation?

How accurate do you need such an approximation to be? A very simple approximation on $[0, 2]$ would be $\ln(\cosh(x)) \approx \frac{3x^{2}}{x^{2}+6}$.

c in your equation represents the speed of light.  You don't have to solve for it;  its well known.

assuming this isnt a joke its actually $-\frac{1}{2}C_d pA$

In my most recent answer the relative error is less than $1$% if $x<3$

I think an approximation may be possible, but it would not be an approximation of $\log(\cosh(x))$. This would give you a big polynomial, and it is famously difficult to find the roots of higher order polynomials analytically. If you want a good numerical solution, it is easy to solve this using Newton's method. To solve for $c$, find an expression that is equal to zero for the correct value of $c$.
$$h=\frac{m \log \left(\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{c} g t}{\sqrt{g m}}\right)\right)}{c} \implies \frac{m \log \left(\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{c} g t}{\sqrt{g m}}\right)\right)}{c} - h = 0$$
So we want to find the root(s) of the following function:
$$f(c) = \frac{m \log \left(\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{c} g t}{\sqrt{g m}}\right)\right)}{c} - h$$
Now, find the first derivative with respect to $c$.
$$f'(c) = \frac{\sqrt{c} t \sqrt{g m} \tanh \left(\frac{\sqrt{c} g t}{\sqrt{g m}}\right)-2 m \log \left(\cosh \left(\frac{\sqrt{c} g t}{\sqrt{g m}}\right)\right)}{2 c^2}$$
Newton's method starts with a guess like $c_0 = 1$ and iterating according to
$$c_n = c_{n-1} - \frac{f(c_{n-1})}{f'(c_{n-1})}$$
For example:
m = 2
g = 2
t = 2
h = 2

def f(c):
    return (m/c) * np.log(np.cosh(t*g / (np.sqrt(m*g)) * np.sqrt(c))) - h

def fprime(c):
    return -2 * m * np.log(np.cosh(t*g / (np.sqrt(m*g)) * np.sqrt(c))) + np.sqrt(c) * np.sqrt(g * m) * t * np.tanh(t*g / (np.sqrt(m*g)) * np.sqrt(c)) / (2 * c**2)

c_guess = 1
for _ in range(1000):
    c_guess = c_guess - f(c_guess)/fprime(c_guess)
    
    if c_guess < 0 or np.isnan(c_guess):
        print('failed to find answer')
        break

print("c value: ", c_guess)
print("convergence: ", f(c_guess))

Testing it for a few sample numbers, whenever an answer exists this finds it quite effectively.
Edit:
This problem is actually a good example of where Newton's method can fail. However, since this is a physics problem, we have some intuition we can apply, which is that there are either 0 roots or 1 root. Since there is only 1 root, and we know it is greater than zero, we can use an incredibly simple method called bisection. Basically, pick three points. If the function changes sign between two of the points, then you know that's where the root is, so we can bisect the smaller range between just those two points. Applied to the parameters in the comments:
m = 0.03
g = 9.8
t = 0.7
h = 2

L = 1e-9
M = 1
R = 1e3

for _ in range(100):

    if np.sign( f(L) ) != np.sign( f(M) ):
        R = M
        M = (L+R)/2
    else:
        L = M
        M = (L+R)/2
    
    print(L, M, R)

print("Answer: ", M)


would the numerical solution work with ln instead of log?
edit: nevermind the log function is log base e for numpy

The method unfortunately fails at when inputting small values (eg t = 0.7, m = 0.03, g = 9.8, h = 2)

Newton's method is great for converging with few function evaluations once you are close to the root.  It can get fooled by a small derivative far from the root.  Numerical Recipes recommends maintaining a bracket on the root and gives some routines.

@Hogu You are correct. This is actually a good example of where Newton's method fails, as Ross pointed out. A very simple method called bisection works much better for this problem. See the edited answer.

Thank you so much!

Alpha will give you the Taylor series with more terms if you ask for them.
$$x^2/2 - x^4/12 + x^6/45 - (17 x^8)/2520 + (31 x^{10})/14175 - (691 x^{12})/935550 + O(x^{13})
$$
After only sixth order the error is large near $\pm 2$ but a few more terms should help a lot.  This will give you a high order polynomial in $c$.  If you find a reasonable approximation any root finding algorithm should work well.  I would use your original equation, not the Taylor approximation for that.
Added:  I often find fixed-point iteration easier to program than other methods.  Write your equation as
$$c=\frac{m}{h}\ln\left(\cosh\left(\frac{tg\sqrt{c}}{\sqrt{mg}}\right)\right)$$
Put an approximate value of $c$ into the right side and compute the left.  Plug that into the right and iterate to (hopeful) convergence.  You want the right to be slowly varying with your parameter.  I am hoping the log and square root will give us that.  If the derivative of the right is less than $1$ in absolute value it will converge with the error being multiplied by the derivative each iteration.

Sorry, for clarification what do you mean by "use your original equation"?

I mean that you should feed your equation before the approximation to the root finder.  Many root finders use derivative information or simulate it from nearby points.  The derivative is not as well modeled as the function value so you may get an incorrect root.

For $0 <x <2$, $[2n,2n]$ Padé approximants $P_n$ are good.
@njuffa already gave
$$P_1=\frac{3 x^2}{x^2+6}$$ Here is $P_2$
$$P_2=\frac{15 x^2 \left(25x^2+126\right)}{62 x^4+1380x^2+3780}$$
Now, considering your equation written as
$$a=\frac 1c\, \log \left(\cosh \left(b\sqrt{c}\right)\right)$$ where $a=\frac h m$ and $b=\frac{t g}{\sqrt{m g}}$
Using the equivalent of $P_2$, this will write
$$\frac a {15b^2}=\frac{25 b^2 c+126}{62 b^4 c^2+1380 b^2 c+3780}$$ which is a quadratic equation in $c$ or in $c b^2$
Using $m=0.3$, $g = 9.8$, $t = 0.7$ and $h = 2$, the above gives $c=0.00840888$ while the solution is $0.00842236$; this seems to be decent.

When an exact function  is available, need an approximation?
$$ y= \log \cosh x, \cosh x= e^{y},~1/\cosh x= e^{-y},\text{subtracting}$$
$$ \sinh y =\frac{\cosh x -1/\cosh x  }{2}$$
$$ y= \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{ \sinh^2 x}{2 \cosh x}\right)$$
An asymptotic approximation for $x>2$ is like
$$ y\approx x- 0.7 $$

I prefer to write a separate answer.
Rewrite the equation as
$$a=\frac{\log (\cosh (x))}{x^2}$$ where
$$a=\frac{h}{g t^2} \qquad \text{and} \qquad x=\frac{g t}{\sqrt{g m}}\sqrt c$$ Build the $[4,4]$ Padé approximant and solve the quadratic equation in $x^2$
$$a=\frac{211 x^4+5985 x^2+19530}{1766x^4+18480 x^2+39060}$$
To give an idea of the accuracy, consider the norm
$$\int_0^2 \Bigg(\frac{\log (\cosh (x))}{x^2} - \frac{211 x^4+5985 x^2+19530}{1766x^4+18480 x^2+39060}  \Bigg)^2\,dx=2.91152\times 10^{-8}$$
Using $m=0.3$, $g = 9.8$, $t = 0.7$ and $h = 2$, converting to decimals, this gives $x^2=1.3483715\cdots$ and then $c=\color{red}{0.00842}38$ which is much better than the previous one (this is become the approximation was done for the rhs as a whole).
